# How do I reference other node in object?

Tags: javascript

I have a js-object that looks like this:

```
Inköp: {
    name: 'Inköp',
    key: 73,
    def: Kvitto,
    menu: {
        Kvitto: {
            key: 75,
            name: 'med kvitto',

        },
        Faktura: {
            key: 70,
            name: 'på faktura',
        }
    }
}
```

The key Def is short for deafult, and is suppose to be used to retrieve Inköp.menu.Kvitto, my current setup doesn't work obviously, how should I do this?

Comment: Set `def` after the object was created. E.g. `foo.bar = foo.baz.xyz;`.

Comment: I wonder if javascript key works with charaters of non-ascii

Comment: @edisonthk: JavaScript is unicode: http://es5.github.io/#x7.6

Comment: @KristofferNolgren thank you for giving me such a nice info and apologize to you also I can't give any help to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can't reference another object node in an object literal from within the same object literal, but you *can* do it from outside the literal. For example, you could do this:

```
var obj = {
    Inköp: {
        name: 'Inköp',
        key: 73,
        menu: {
            Kvitto: {
                key: 75,
                name: 'med kvitto',

            },
            Faktura: {
                key: 70,
                name: 'på faktura',
            }
        }
    }
};
obj.def = obj.Inköp.menu.Kvitto;
```

You could also set `def` to a string value, `"Kvitto"`, which you could then access from outside the literal like this:

```
obj.Inköp.menu[obj.Inköp.def];
```

It depends on if you want succinctness in declaring your literal or in using it.